# Making a dataframe where new row is created after every nth column using only semi colons as delimiters

Tags: python, pandas, string, csv, delimiter

I have the following string in a column within a row in a pandas dataframe. You could just treat it as a string.

```
;2;613;12;1;Ajc hw EEE;13;.387639;1;EXP;13;2;128;12;1;NNN XX Ajc;13;.208966;1;SGX;13;..
```

It goes on like that.

I want to convert it into a table and use the semi colon `;` symbol as a delimiter. The problem is there is no new line delimiter and I have to estimate it to be every 10 items.

So, it should look something like this.

```
;2;613;12;1;Ajc hw EEE;13;.387639;1;EXP;13;
 2;128;12;1;NNN XX Ajc;13;.208966;1;SGX;13;..
```

How do I convert that string into a new dataframe in pandas. After every 10 semi colon delimiters, a new row should be created.

I have no idea how to do this, any help would be greatly appreciated in terms of tools or ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
# removing first value as it's a semi colon
data = ';2;613;12;1;Ajc hw EEE;13;.387639;1;EXP;13;2;128;12;1;NNN XX Ajc;13;.208966;1;SGX;13;'[1:] 
data = data.split(';')
row_count = len(data)//10

data = [data[x*10:(x+1)*10] for x in range(row_count)]
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I used a double slash for dividing but as your data length should be dividable by 10, you can use only one.

Here's a screenshot of my output.
[image]